# форма для поиска в sql базе

Tags: php, javascript, sql, веб-программирование

Интересует вот какая тема, можно ли и есди да то как реализовать поиск по базе с переменной в sql запросе так чтобы использовать только один search-box или же чтобы в кнопку вставить sql запрос без  инжекта

Comment: Вы можете более корректно сформулировать вопрос ?

Comment: @madfan41k, мне надо выполнить запрос по поиску типа SELECT * FROM `baze` WHERE id LIKE '%$val%', я знаю как сделать для одного столбца, но хотелось бы чтобы оно искало по всей таблице

Comment: where id like '%$val%'
       or name like '%$val%'
       or field3 like '%$val%'

Comment: @Tony DM %LIKE% не использует индекс, а если его еще использовать по нескольким столбцам то это просто извращение

Comment: @TonyDM, то есть грубо говоря перебрать через or все столбцы

Comment: @Elanyl настоятельно рекомендую вам так не делать, так как время отработки этого запроса будет уменьшатся с каждой новой записью в таблицу

Comment: @madfan41k, лучше все таки полнотекстный поиск по базе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для реализации этого функционала необходимо использовать [Полнотекстовый поиск](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html)

```
SELECT name, description FROM table WHERE MATCH (row_1, row_n) AGAINST ('search text');
```